# Preview is broken EE5

Tags: ee5

I'm trying to preview in article but I'm getting a bunch of errors on the page (see image below). What could it be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a server parameter setting, update, from ICU lib

> I encountered this issue too, this problem may not be always related to PHP version, I have seen the problem on my customer server with PHP 5.6 version.
>
> The INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 constant is available in PHP 5.4.0 but the intl extension uses the ICU system lib and some servers have a really old version of the ICU lib. Support for UTS 46 Unicode IDNA Compatibility Processing was added in ICU 4.6 and released on
>
> In most cases, this happens on hosting providers who sell shared hostings and did not fixed this issue on their side don't want to assist their customers to update the ICU lib "because it's shared hosting"

Source:
https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-69780.html

Comment: Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Seems yo be not relared  to Expresssiom Engine, but to  your hosting provider.

Comment: What version of PHP should I be using?